# In DownloadPipelineArtifact@0 how do you you change pipelineId from meaning buildId and instead mean pipelineId

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using Azure DevOps I'm trying to download an artifact created by a different pipeline.

The artifact is created by the pipeline:

`https://dev.azure.com/[Group]/[Project Name]/_apps/hub/ms.vss-build-web.ci-designer-hub?pipelineId=34&branch=Dev`

Using the following task

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: 'Transactions DB\bin\Debug'
    artifact: 'theDacpacTransactionsDBDev'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

In the URL I see `pipelineId = 34`
When I click on the artifacts published by the run I get the following url
`https://dev.azure.com/[Group]/[Project Name]/_build/results?buildId=2303&view=results`
where I can see `buildId = 2303` (This values changes each time the pipeline runs).

In the pipeline trying the download the artifact uses the following task

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
   artifactName: 'theDacpacTransactionsDBDev'
   pipelineId: 34
   targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Dev'
```

and I get the following log and error:

```
Starting: DownloadPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Download pipeline artifact
Description  : Downloads an artifact associated with a pipeline
Version      : 0.140.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
Download from the specified build: #34
Download artifact to: C:\Agent\_work\13\Dev
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session [GUID]
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender did not correlate any events with X-TFS-Session [GUID]
##[error]The requested build 34 could not be found.
Finishing: DownloadPipelineArtifact
```

If I change pipelineId to 2303 it now works.

What am I missing here? How do I target the latest artifacts created by a pipeline?

Comment: Did you start by looking at the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the latest artifact you can use this (if you produce and consume in the same pipeline)

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifact: 'theDacpacTransactionsDBDev'
    path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\Dev
```

but if you want to get latest from another pipeline it would be:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    source: 'specific'
    project: 'FabrikamFiber'
    pipeline: 34
    runVersion: 'latest'
    artifact: 'theDacpacTransactionsDBDev'
```

Comment: @Mandelbrotter could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?